# how to filter biggest and smallest number from a 4 column text file

Tags: bash, sorting

I am new to Linux and bash. I have file captured from Iperf network performance and throughput tool. The file is huge so i did not attached it. But it looks like this :

```
bin/iperf.exe -s -P 0 -i 1 -p 5001 -w 8192.0K -N -f m
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 8.00 MByte
------------------------------------------------------------
[148] local 192.168.0.14 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.12 port 49504
[260] local 192.168.0.14 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.12 port 49501
[276] local 192.168.0.14 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.12 port 49502
[292] local 192.168.0.14 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.12 port 49503
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[148]  0.0- 1.0 sec  0.00 MBytes  0.00 Mbits/sec
[148]  1.0- 2.0 sec  0.00 MBytes  0.00 Mbits/sec
[148]  2.0- 3.0 sec  0.01 MBytes  0.07 Mbits/sec
[276]  0.0- 1.0 sec  2.67 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec
[SUM]  0.0- 3.0 sec  2.68 MBytes  7.49 Mbits/sec
[292]  0.0- 1.0 sec  3.21 MBytes  26.9 Mbits/sec
[148]  3.0- 4.0 sec  1.75 MBytes  14.7 Mbits/sec
[260]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.86 MBytes  15.6 Mbits/sec
[292]  1.0- 2.0 sec  5.08 MBytes  42.6 Mbits/sec
[SUM]  0.0- 4.0 sec  11.9 MBytes  25.0 Mbits/sec
[148]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1.10 MBytes  9.25 Mbits/sec
[276]  1.0- 2.0 sec  2.59 MBytes  21.7 Mbits/sec
[260]  1.0- 2.0 sec  1.21 MBytes  10.2 Mbits/sec
[292]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.65 MBytes  13.9 Mbits/sec
[SUM]  1.0- 5.0 sec  6.56 MBytes  13.8 Mbits/sec
[260]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.97 MBytes  16.5 Mbits/sec
[276]  2.0- 3.0 sec  3.42 MBytes  28.7 Mbits/sec
[148]  5.0- 6.0 sec  1.81 MBytes  15.2 Mbits/sec
[260]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.09 MBytes  17.5 Mbits/sec
[SUM]  2.0- 6.0 sec  9.29 MBytes  19.5 Mbits/sec
```

And then we have hell lot of data in similar patterns. I want to find the Highest and Lowest "Mbits/sec" value from the file . This file can be saved as .txt or .csv (if that helps). I tried some sort and awk filters experiments but no use till  now.

The sort filter i tried was

Comment: FYI - i need to sort and find largest and smalled values only based from the "[SUM]" fields

Comment: You should edit your question.

Comment: Did you try my code?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
awk '/^\[SUM]/ { 
    min = !min || $7 < min ? $7 : min
    max = $7 > max ? $7 : max 
} END { print "min:", min, "max:", max }' file
```

When [SUM] is matched at the start of the line, use a ternary operator to overwrite the minimum and maximum values if necessary. Once the file has been processed, print the minimum and maximum value.

Output:

```
min: 7.49 max: 25.0
```